# Is there any alternative for window.showModalDialog for chrome?

Tags: javascript, showmodaldialog

I am using window.open instead of window.showModalDialog , when we use window.showModalDialog we cannot able to access any thing until some response is given from the popup window. I am able to replicate some of the feature by using window.open, like disabling the click of mouse in the parent window. but I am not able to achieve

1. Disable all other tabs in chrome. is it possible in chrome?
2. not able to close parent window when we click cancel in popup window? - how can I close parent window by clicking cancel in popup window.

Comment: 1. not possible.   2. also not possible (expect in FF with an about:config set).

Comment: You shouldn't even want to do that. Your users will be really frustrated. If you want something like this, just use something like [bootstrap's dialog](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). Elegant and friendly.

Comment: I am working on a project which will run on IE previously, but now i want to make it available on chrome, without any change in business functionality. so i want to do that.